# How to play, pause and stop a video in the buttons of GUI created in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, ffmpeg

I have created a GUI in Python. In the GUI I have three buttons, Play, Pause and Stop. On the click of the respective buttons, i want the respective tasks to be done, that is, play, pause and stop a video. Any body have any idea please help me. This is what i have tried to do so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os
import vlc

root=Tk()
root.title("ARP")
root.geometry("200x100")


def play():
left_video = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","\\C:\FFmpegTool\\bin\\samplevideo.mp4"])

right_video = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","\\C:\FFmpegTool\\bin\\rotate1.mp4"])


app=Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1=Button(app, text="Play", command=play)
button1.grid()

button2=Button(app)
button2.grid()
button2.configure(text="Pause")

button3=Button(app)
button3.grid()
button3.configure(text="Stop")

root.mainloop()
```

Please help me.